# How to become an observer of a property of an object stored in an NSArray?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to make a view controller an observer of a property (an enum) of one of its child view controllers. The view controller whose property I am trying to access is stored in an NSArray.
It seems that I cannot do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"[[noteControllers objectAtIndex:1] currentAnimationStatus]" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

so how do I observe the currentAnimationStatus property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
UIViewController *controller = [noteControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[controller addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"currentAnimationStatus"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:nil];
```

You should get callback to

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```